# Default value for REST resource method

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

If i have 2 search fields for a search: id, name. if i did not enter values in both fields, what would be the default values for them. how should i write an sql query to get "all" records in such a case.
I am using JERSEY 2.0

Comment: You could improve your question by showing some code that will better explain exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It could be valid to return all values. However, it is usually not good to return a potentially large amount of results.

Therefore, all your responses should have a maximum number of results, with the option of repeating the query with a different offset to get the other results (That's similar to pagination).